# PHP Comparing Values From While Loop Outside Of Loop

Tags: php, function

I'm trying to find the best way to compare dates outside a `while statement`. I wrote a function and set the while loop inside. Taking in account that I need to compare every single date from the loop with `$this_new_date`, how can I achieve this?

```
 function getDates(){
 $returnDates = array();
 while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($allDatesQuery)){
 $returnDates[] = date("Y-n-j",strtotime($result['date']));
}}


if($returnDates===$this_new_date){

//do something here
}
```

Comment: why not just do the check inside while loop, set a flag that your condition match and proceed... or you could use [array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti: Okay thanks for the documentation. It's interesting. But for education sake, how would you go about doing what you suggest?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Please note that if you are going to use the MySQLi extension (http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) you will need to use a `while` loop to store your data unless you are running PHP >= 5.3 in which case you can use `mysqli_fetch_all` (http://php.net/mysqli_fetch_all).

**Option 1**

Perform the date comparison **inside the query**. This is going to be your absolute best/fastest option. That way PHP does not even need to do anything.

Example:

`SELECT * FROM table WHERE date = ?;`

Then use a prepared statement to pass your date value to the query: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

**Option 2**

Assuming you need to perform this date comparison in PHP the `while` loop is still going to be the fastest because unless the date you're looking for is the very last record you can likely get away without having to read the entire query result.

```
function is_date_in_query($this_new_date, $allDatesQuery) {
    while($result = mysqli_fetch_array($allDatesQuery)) {
        if (strtotime($this_new_date) == strtotime($result['date'])) {
            return TRUE;
        }
    }
    return FALSE;
}

if (is_date_in_query($this_new_date, $allDatesQuery)) {
    // yes the date is inside - do something
}
else {
    // no the date is not inside - do something else
}
```

**But** you say you cannot use a `while` loop so let's look at another option.

**Option 3**

Use a combination of `mysqli_fetch_all`, `in_array` and `array_column`. This prevents any `while` loops but requires you to load the entire query result.

Example:

```
// Put ALL rows into an array
$result_array = mysqli_fetch_all($allDatesQuery, MYSQLI_ASSOC);

// Check if the date is anywhere in the result array
if (in_array(date('Y-m-d', strtotime($this_new_date)), array_column($result_array, 'date'))) {
    // yes the date is inside - do something
}
else {
    // no the date is not inside - do something else
}
```

Here is a working example (updated): https://eval.in/868105

Comment: Thanks for this complete answer. I do know how to make use of prepared statements. I just wanted to make the question simpler by avoiding a long code. I'm guessing if I need to reformat the dates with your 3rd option, I should do `($result_array, date("Y-n-j",strtotime('date'))`?

Comment: I've updated the third example and the demo link. I would suggest you alter the date you're searching for instead of altering all of the database results. Or, you could use `DATE_FORMAT` (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_date-format) to change how the date is returned from the database.

Comment: Thanks. But `$this_new_date` is already formatted with `date("Y-n-j)`. Thats why I need to reformat the database dates so that it can be compared with `$this_new_date`.

Comment: I understand, but to compare the dates in your format you will then need to transform ALL the database rows from what I assume is `YYYY-MM-DD` format. This is counterintuitive and it's easier to convert the one value for comparison. Or, like I mentioned before, use the MySQL `DATE_FORMAT` (or similar function if using a different database) so that the dates are already in your desired format. The example code does not actually change the format of `$this_new_date`.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like this:

```
...    
$matchedDates = array_filter($returnDates, function($value) use($this_new_date){
    return $value == $this_new_date;
});
var_dump($matchedDates);
```